# Working with Brownie scripts using Flask

Tags: solidity, brownie, flask

My projects is built like this:
React frontend -> Flask server to interact, save to SQL etc.. -> Brownie project.

Now when trying to use a script from brownie in my flask file:

```
from brownieProject.scripts.deploy import get_account
```

I get an error where:

```
cannot import name 'Puzzle' from 'brownie'
```

The Puzzle is the name of my contract, and it seems to not recognize it if i try to use it in the Flask script.
My question here is how can i use thos Brownie scripts outside of the brownie project? is it even how it's supposed to be? if not, how should i use it within a Flask venv so i could run dynamic scripts using my frontend?

Note: if i remove the Puzzle contract import from the deploy.py in brownieProjects.scripts i get it compiled, so it only fails to bring up the contract.

Thank You for the help!